# logstash if field exists then grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, grok, logstash-file

I'm trying to create a filter for logstash that will have "general" grok filter for all logs and if some field exists, then I want it to perform a different grok.

The first grok I'm using is

```
grok {
match => [
"message", "....%{NOTSPACE:name} %{GREEDYDATA:logcontent}" 
]
}
```

This is working great. But I want this to be able to filter even more if the "name" field is i.e "foo"

```
if [name] == "foo" {
grok {
match => [
"message", ".....%{NOTSPACE:name} %{NOTSPACE:object1} %{NOTSPACE:object2}" 
]
}
```

I tried this option but it didn't work.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a pattern match on the message before you grok anything.

For example:

```
if [message] =~ /....foo/ {
   // foo specific grok here
} else {
   // general grok
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that i will need to put an example of the entire log in "if [message] =~ /.....foo/ ? or can I actually put the dots there and write the word I'm interested in ?

Comment: Just put enough to know that your grok will succeed.